# VMWare IP Question

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have Mac that has an IP, not of the kind 192.168...
I have a Windows guest OS in my VMWare Fusion, and its IP is of the kind 192.168...
I have report server running on my Windows virtual machine.

I need to have a coworker, who has a non 192.168... address surf to my virtual machine's report server, but he is unable to, i'm guessing because of the 192.168.. issue.
Can I make my virtual machine get a non 192.168... IP like the other machines in our office?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your VM's settings, under the "network" part, change it from "Share the Mac's network connection (NAT)" to "Connect directly to the physical network (Bridged)". This should allow it to pick up a proper IP from the network like any true physical computer.

Comment: Glad that did the trick. :-)